# Partial Order relation conditions (transitive)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, relations

We know that every Partial Order Set has to satisfy three conditions :

1- Reflexive

2- Anti-Symmetric

3- Transitive

For example : $$S= \left(\left\{1 \right\},\left\{2 \right\},\left\{3 \right\},\left\{1,2 \right\}  \right)$$

And the relation is $\subseteq$ ,My question is why this Set **S** is a Partial Order Set Althought I Cannot prove that is ***Transitive*** which is defined as:

$$R=\{(x,y)\} ; xRy ~\text{and}~ yRz \implies xRz$$
I could not find like : **if**  $\left\{1 \right\} \subseteq \left\{1,2 \right\}\text{ } and \text{ } \left\{1,2 \right\}  \subseteq \text{ }\text{ } ?? \text{ }then\text{ } ??$

in another way how can we apply the Transitive test for this set **S**?

Comment: Recall the definition of a transitive relation: A relation $R$ on a set $A$ is transitive if **whenever** $(a,b)\in R$ and $(b,c)\in R \implies (a,c)\in R$ for $a,b,c \in A$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that statement of the form of "if $A$ then $B$" is true if $A$ is false.

Well, actually we have $\color{blue}{\{1 \}} \subseteq \color{green}{\{ 1,2\}}$ and $\color{green}{\{1,2\}} \subseteq \color{purple}{\{ 1, 2\}}$, then $\color{blue}{\{1\}} \subseteq \color{purple}{\{1,2\}}.$

Notice that for the subset operation, we always have

$$x \subseteq y \text{ and }y \subseteq z \text{ ,then }x \subseteq z$$

Comment: like that ..
i understand the first line
but do you mean that  **y** may  equel to **z**?

Comment: There is no restriction that $x$, $y$ and $z$ have to be distinct right? we are suppose to check all possibilities. though the case for identical elements are trivial. Most important thing should be the last line to show transitivity.

Comment: Perfect  then i can understand that A relation **⊆** on a set **A**:
 is always _Transitive_  .. right ?

 _Where **A** is a Set of at least One Element ._

Comment: yes, subset is a transitive relation.

Comment: thanks a lot bro..
in the definition of a transitive relation: A relation **R** on a set **A** is transitive if **whenever** (a,b)∈R(a,b)∈R and (b,c)∈R⟹(a,c)∈R(b,c)∈R⟹(a,c)∈R for a,b,c∈A ...

could a,b and c be  equel ?
@rohan

Comment: There is no restriction that forbids them from being equal. so yes, they can be equal.